# Cannot use classes from .jar file

Tags: java, gradle, jar, dependencies

I've made a .jar with .java classes and tried to import them into my project, but it doesn't work.

When I build the project, I get:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
error: package skija does not exist
import static skija.scenes.*;
```

In my gradle I've tried to add this .jar via multiple methods and none of them work 
build.gradle:

```
repositories {
flatDir {
    dirs 'lib'
   } 
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', includes: ['*.jar'])
    implementation files('lib/scenes.jar')
    implementation name: 'scenes'
}
```

Additionally, I've modified settings.gradle, which doesn't change anything:

```
pluginManagement {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            flatDir {
                dirs 'lib'
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath fileTree(dir: 'lib', includes: ['*.jar'])
            classpath name: 'scenes'
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I've added libraries from the Idea Project Structure Libraries.
One is pointing to *lib* folder, and another points directly to the .jar file. This didn't help either.

I use a `jar.bat` script placed inside of PATH that calls jar.exe 
jar.bat:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin\jar.exe" %*
```

The scenes.jar was made with `jar cfv scenes.jar *` command. 
Snipped of `jar tf scenes.jar`:

```
>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin\jar.exe" tf scenes.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
skija/scenes/
skija/scenes/BitmapImageScene.java
skija/scenes/BitmapScene.java
skija/scenes/BlendsScene.java
skija/scenes/BreakIteratorScene.java
skija/scenes/CodecScene.java
skija/scenes/ColorFiltersScene.java
skija/scenes/DebugTextBlobHandler.java
skija/scenes/DebugTextRun.java
skija/scenes/DecorationsBenchScene.java
skija/scenes/DrawableScene.java
skija/scenes/EmptyScene.java
skija/scenes/FigmaScene.java
skija/scenes/FontRenderingScene.java
skija/scenes/FontScene.java
skija/scenes/FontSizeScene.java
skija/scenes/FontVariationsScene.java
skija/scenes/GeometryScene.java
skija/scenes/HUD.java
skija/scenes/ImageBenchScene.java
skija/scenes/ImageCodecsScene.java
skija/scenes/ImageFiltersScene.java
skija/scenes/ImagesScene.java
skija/scenes/MaskFiltersScene.java
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point sticking `.java` files in a jar file. You need to compile the java files, which produces `.class` files. Put those in the jar file.